# File movement and string manipulation on batch scripting

Tags: string, batch-file, batch-processing

Sorry if my question is not clear. I tried a part of the problem but couldn't proceed.

Folder structure

```
Home
 A A1 - stdinxx.csv  (xx - 2 digit number)
   A2 - sapvdyy.csv  (yy - 2 digit number)
   A3
    .
    .
    .
   AN
B  B1 - stdin.csv
   B2 - sapvd.csv 
   B3
    .
    .
    .
   BN
```

mybat.bat

mybat.bat should be at Home folder. A and B are subfolders.A and B has subfolders within them (not fixed number but numbers of subfolders matches on A and B).

I do a for loop and get all file names within sub folder of Home(issue here).

```
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('Dir /A:-D /b /s *.csv 2^>nul') do If exist "%%a" ( copy %%a B\subfolder_based_upon_file_input\%%~ni.csv)
```

How do I do for loop for only A folder and subfolders for *.csv?

How do I remove last 2 digit while copying (thought %%%i:~-2% would work...doesn't)?

How do I trim the filepath to get A1 or A2 so that I could copy files from A1 to B1 and so on?

Any direction or idea would save my life. Plz.

Flow I was thinking.

Do a search for *.csv file on folder 'A' and it's subfolder.

Get the names of file

Trim down the name of the file so that 2 digit are gone(file will always contain 2 digit numeric value)

Get the folder name from filepath where file resides (1 from A1)

Copy the trimmed file to B\B(1)\

Please help. Please.

Comment: Please edit your question and try to format the source. Use the preview to see if it's readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'xcopy /l /s "%sourcedir%\A\*.csv" '
 ) DO IF EXIST "%%a" (
 SET "destfilename=%%~na"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%s IN ("%%~dpa.") DO ECHO f|XCOPY "%%a" "%sourcedir%\B\%%~nxs\!destfilename:~0,-2!.csv" >nul
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I take it you want to reproduce the directory structure under `A` to an identical structure under `B` except that the filenames have the last two characters removed.

Your example appears artificial. Much better to post a representative real structure. The above code will produce uunder `B` subdirectories named `A*` - whic can be changed if required.

The `%%x:~m,n` syntax isn't supported, which is why it didn't work. You need to put the values into an ordinary environment variable and use the `delayedexpansion` methodology as demonstrated. If you want to manipulate the destination subdirectorynames - then follow the bouncing ball, using the subdirectoryname in `%%~nxs`